# Android: image size to fit any screen

Tags: android, image

In my app, users will upload their own images to a web service to be stored. These images can be any size, taken with any phone, or just images taken with a camera by the user.

So, what should be the processing, before uploading the images to the server, so that, when other users download these images, they will be decently displayed on their devices, whatever the model, the screen size..etc??

- Should the app have any restriction for too small or too big images?.
- Should I by default try to make all images to `Extra High or Extra Extra High DPI` so it will be easy to scale them down?

I am using the following piece of code to read the device screen, can these values be used to scale images according to needs?

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    deviceWidth = size.x;
    deviceHeight = size.y;
```

Comment: As far as I know instagram uses 1024px as width - so I'd recommend to use the same size as the pros ;)

Comment: android:scaletype:"fitXY" please try this in your imageview,,,,,

Comment: Please do NOT download the full scale image, (if users can upload any size) or you will end up with a flood of outOfMemory exceptions and sacrifice the network traffic for images that get scaled down anyhow. Do a serverside scaling when requesting a resource beforehand and use a convenient image loading library like Picasso or Glide for displaying the images.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html

Comment: Fully agree with what @JacksOnFire said. I would also like to add that you could use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` in the app to display the image after it downloaded, because that would fit the image into the screen with ratio intact on any screen.